# Can not set sheet name with dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

I am exporting multiple dataframe in a list to different sheet in one excel file, and I can do this with the below code(use `mtcars` as an example):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ImportExport)

data_list <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
table_name <- names(data_list)

# Run
excel_export(data_list, "foo.xlsx", table_names = tab_name)
```

And then, I want to do this with another way, cause I see the dplyr document said that:

> `.y` to refer to the key, a one row tibble with one column per
>   grouping variable that identifies the group.

So I thought `.y` equal to my created variable `table_name`, and I do this:

```
data_list %>% excel_export("foo.xlsx", table_names = .y)
```

Then I got an error:

> Error in .jcall(wb, "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet;",
>   "createSheet",  :    object '.y' not found

Could someone explain why and how can I do this with `.y`.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you find that quote in document? I think you should use `data_list %>% excel_export("foo.xlsx", table_names = tab_name)`

Comment: Hi @RonakShah, I know you.You answer me on [my another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674329/how-to-create-a-variable-that-indicate-where-the-data-from-in-every-list-element) a couple days ago. The code ```purrr::imap(df1, ~dplyr::mutate(.x, from = .y))``` you provided really helps me. I don't know what `.x` and `.y` exactly mean and then I searched dplyr document with `.x` and `.y` as keyword seperately. I found something about them on page 38 described in `group_map` function. So I imitated your previous code contains `.y` to solve this problem.

Comment: `.x` and `.y` are *placeholders* to be used in the expression to be called. Imagine underneath `group_walk` something like this: `for (.y in names(thedata)) { .x <- thedata[[.y]]; expr; }` where the `expr`ession that you provide will then see the `.x` and `.y` variables as objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you reference a quote, I think it makes sense to use the function in which that quote is used. In this case, I found it in `group_map` (which includes `group_walk`, a complementary function that operates primarily in side-effect).
2. You still need to `group_by` the data. More specifically, it needs to operate on a `tbl_df` (not a `list`), typically (but not always) a *grouped* tibble.

I have neither `ImportExport` nor `xlsx` (on which the former depends) installed, so I'll proxy your action with `write.csv`.

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  group_walk(~ write.csv(.x, paste0(.y, ".csv")))
```

The side-effect of this is that three files are created in the current directory named `4.csv`, `6.csv`, and `8.csv`.

If you want to operate on a named list, one could also use one of:

```r
# using: data_list <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
purrr::imap(data_list,
            ~ write.csv(.x, paste0("~/Downloads/", .y, ".csv")))
Map(write.csv, data_list, paste0(names(data_list), ".csv"))
```

The effect is the same.

Answer (score 1):

`.x` and `.y` are not global parameters that can be used anywhere, those are reserved for specific functions. (usually `map`)

From `?map`

> .f A function, formula, or vector (not necessarily atomic).
>
> If a formula, e.g. ~ .x + 2, it is converted to a function. There are three ways to refer to the arguments:
>
> - For a single argument function, use .
> - For a two argument function, use .x and .y
> - For more arguments, use ..1, ..2, ..3 etc

Let's take a simple list

```
library(purrr)
listvec1 <- list(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = 2:4)
```

1) Let's say we want to multiply every element in the list with 2, `map` has a single argument so we use `.` here.

```
map(listvec1, ~. * 2)
#$a
#[1] 2 4 6

#$b
#[1]  8 10 12

#$c
#[1] 4 6 8
```

Coincidently `.x` works here as well :

```
map(listvec1, ~.x * 2)
```

but if you use `.y` it will give an error because there are no 2 arguments in `map`.

```
map(listvec, ~.y * 2)
```

> Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : the ... list contains fewer than 2 elements

2) Let's take another list and now add `listvec1` with `listvec2`. For this, we can use `map2` which has two arguments so here we refer them as `.x` and `.y`.

```
listvec2 <- list(a = 7, b = 8, c = 9)
map2(listvec1,listvec2, ~.x + .y)
#you could actually simplify this as but anyway this is just an example
#map2(listvec1,listvec2, `+`)

#$a
#[1]  8  9 10

#$b
#[1] 12 13 14

#$c
#[1] 11 12 13
```

In the same we use `.x` and `.y` in `imap` where `.x` is the element and `.y` is either the name of the list (if present) or index.

---

In the post above `.y` means nothing, so using it as

```
data_list %>% excel_export("foo.xlsx", table_names = .y)
```

would definitely yield an error. You need to use specific functions as described above to use `.x`, `.y`. So if you want to use pipes for your command, you should use

```
data_list %>% excel_export("foo.xlsx", table_names = tab_name)
```